# What's this icon on raspberry pi 3?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wpa

I'm working on a project for my college, but the university wifi is making it a huge hassle to connect to it. I'm trying to connect to a WPA EAP, but the connection is greyed out and there's this icon.[image]

Could someone tell me what the icon means? I've tried to connecting to it through using network blocks in the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf.